# shuffling randomly 2 numpy arrays synced as efficient as possible

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to shuffle data that I collected for my neural network.

The numpy arrays look like: `np.shape(input)=(50,9)` and `np.shape(output)=(50,50)`
I want them obviously to be shuffled synced as I want to train a network with valid data. My goal is that I want to swap element `input[2][0:9]` with `input[32][0:9]` and when this happens the column `32` and `2` swap in the output array and row `32` and `2` swap. As I have about 10 million arrays for-looping or creating empty arrays and then filling them is very taxing on compute time. Do you know of a elegant solution to this?
It should be randomized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shuffle the first dimension then slice:

```
x = np.arange(len(input))

# shuffle the index
np.random.shuffle(x)

# reindex
input, output = input[x], output[x]
```

Another approach is to generate a random list and use `argsort`:

```
x = np.argsort(np.random.rand(len(input)))
input, output = input[x], output[x]
```

Comment: Right, except, both rows and columns of the output should be shuffled, if I understood correctly.

Comment: can I use `input, output= input[x], output[x]`
and then `output=output[:,x]` as I want columnd and row shuffled the same?

Comment: @zvone Last thing you want in training a ML model is to shuffle the features. Same to OP, unless you are trying to train something that is agnostic to feature order.

Comment: @SergeantIdiot see comment above. Also, no, `x` doesn't have the same length as the second axis of `output`.

Comment: the output is a symmetrical matrix and must remain symmatrical after the shuffling. The out has to be shuffled in both directions

Comment: Then you want to shuffle the rows separately with a different `x`. Also, you *should* shuffle each row differently.